# Is there a way to get CSS class defintions from the VS2012 CSHTML code editor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to click on a CSS class in the VS2012 View code editor to get the class definitions, like "Go to definition" for Classes etc.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Linked to this question is how to ascertain the CSS that is applying to a textbox/html.editfor helper. I thought the "width" would be stored in the "edit-field" class, but it is not !??!

.editor-field {
    margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;

Comment: Ah...... :) Now I have a reason !!!

Comment: I have just added an edit to my question which was the reason why I was asking ie how to work out what to determining the width of the HTML.EditFor helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 6.0, ReSharper supports CSS:

> http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/whatsnew_60.html#CSS
>
> You can easily find usages of a CSS property or selector both within the current file and in a larger scope.

Edit:

> Linked to this question is how to ascertain the CSS that is applying to a textbox/html.editfor helper.

No, that is a completely new question. You can check this with debugging tools in your browser, F12 in IE.

Comment: OK thanks.... Sorry I did not mean to question creep... Huge thanks for your help.